How to add text with an outline (stroke) in React Native with Expo Go?
I'm working on a React Native app using Expo Go, and I want to add an outline (stroke) effect to text. I've encountered several challenges despite trying multiple approaches. Here's what I've attempted so far:

react-native-text-stroke library:
I tried using this library, but it doesn’t work as expected. On Android, the text doesn’t render at all. On iOS, I couldn’t test it thoroughly due to installation issues (e.g., pod install), and I haven’t found a reliable solution for this library yet.

SVG Texts:
I considered using SVG texts to create the outline effect. However, SVG doesn’t handle text wrapping (multiline text) well. I tried implementing text wrapping manually, but I faced another issue:
I used onLayout to get the dimensions of the text, but the hook never gets called, even when I set a height of 1 (to ensure a minimum layout). This makes it difficult to adapt the text size and handle dynamic dimensions, especially when the width is set to 100%. This complicates managing multiline text significantly.

Text Shadows with Offset:
I explored using textShadow with multiple offsets to simulate an outline. While this approach works to some extent, it has issues on Android. When I apply negative offsets (e.g., width: -5px), the shadows are clipped or cut off, even if I minimize the shadow radius to avoid a blurred effect. The rendering issue ruins the clean outline effect I’m trying to achieve.


On the web side of my project, I can use solutions like WebKit to handle text outlines easily. However, I’m looking for a specific solution for React Native with Expo Go, as that’s where the main issues lie.
If anyone has faced a similar problem or knows a functional solution for adding a clean text outline in React Native, I’d greatly appreciate your advice!
Thanks in advance for your help.
react-native-text-stroke, textShadow with style, svg text
